# CUDA thrust vector: copy and sum the values from device_vectorA to device_vectorB

Tags: vector, cuda, thrust

I'm new to CUDA.

I want to copy and sum values in `device_vector` in the following ways. Are there more efficient ways (or functions provided by thrust) to implement these?

```
thrust::device_vector<int> device_vectorA(5);
thrust::device_vector<int> device_vectorB(20);
```

1. copy`device_vectorA` 4 times into `device_vectorB` in the following way:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        offset_sta = i * 5;

        thrust::copy(device_vectorA.begin(), device_vectorA.end(), device_vectorB.begin() + offset_sta);
    }
```

2. Sum every 5 values in `device_vectorB` and store the results in new device_vector (size 4):

```
// Example
device_vectorB = 1 2 3 4 5 | 1 2 3 4 5 | 1 2 3 4 5 | 1 2 3 4 5 
device_vectorC =     15          15           15           15
```

```
thrust::device_vector<int> device_vectorC(4);

for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        offset_sta = i * 5;
        offset_end = (i + 1) * 5 - 1;

        device_vectorC[i] = thrust::reduce(device_vectorB.begin() + offset_sta, device_vectorB.begin() + offset_end, 0);
    }
```

Are there more efficient ways (or functions provided by thrust) to implement these?

P.S. 1 and 2 are separate instances. For simplicity, these two instances just use the same vectors to illustrate.

Comment: If you do step 1 as shown in your question, how does device_vectorB wind up the way you show in step 2?

Comment: @talonmies Sry about that I just gave random values. Changed in the question.

Comment: OK, so why don't you just reduce device_vectorA once and copy the result 5 times?

Comment: These are two separate questions. For simplicity, I just use the same vectors to illustrate. I omit many operations during these two operations in my project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step 1 can be done with a single thrust::copy operation using a permutation iterator that uses a transform iterator working on a counting iterator to generate the copy indices "on the fly".

Step 2 is a partitioned reduction, using thrust::reduce_by_key.  We can again use a transform iterator working on a counting iterator to create the flags array "on the fly".

Here is an example:

```
$ cat t2124.cu
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <thrust/reduce.h>
#include <thrust/sequence.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/permutation_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/transform_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/counting_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/discard_iterator.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace thrust::placeholders;
const int As = 5;
const int Cs = 4;
const int Bs = As*Cs;
int main(){

  thrust::device_vector<int> A(As);
  thrust::device_vector<int> B(Bs);
  thrust::device_vector<int> C(Cs);
  thrust::sequence(A.begin(), A.end(), 1);  // fill A with 1,2,3,4,5
  thrust::copy_n(thrust::make_permutation_iterator(A.begin(), thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::counting_iterator<int>(0), _1%A.size())), B.size(), B.begin());  // step 1
  auto my_flags_iterator = thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::counting_iterator<int>(0), _1/A.size());
  thrust::reduce_by_key(my_flags_iterator, my_flags_iterator+B.size(), B.begin(), thrust::make_discard_iterator(), C.begin()); // step 2
  thrust::host_vector<int> Ch = C;
  thrust::copy_n(Ch.begin(), Ch.size(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ","));
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
$ nvcc -o t2124 t2124.cu
$ compute-sanitizer ./t2124
========= COMPUTE-SANITIZER
15,15,15,15,
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

If we wanted to, even the device vector `A` could be dispensed with; that could be created "on the fly" using a counting iterator.  But presumably your inputs are not actually 1,2,3,4,5

Comment: Perfect, this is actually more efficient when the array size becomes large in my project. I will try to use iterators to implement other functions although it's a bit difficult for me now.